# Beep PC Motherboard Speaker in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, speakers

I need to beep an internal hardware PC Speaker on Motherboard from Cmd Prompt or a batch in Win 10 64-bit. The most useful [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt) here on the subject offers some apps and drivers for Win 7 32/64-bit, but none works in Win 10 64-bit as per my tests except in Test Mode, as the 64-bit [system speaker driver](http://www.waldbauer.com/tmp/dl.php?download=beepxp64) is unsigned.

Note that the integrated small PC Speaker is not driven by any Audio Card or audio chip, and it beeps OK now driven by the Mobo system speaker driver at PC startup, but not after loading Win 10. I'm aware of support for PC System Speaker removed from 64-bit Windows versions, but may be 3rd party solutions exist? Or someone would help to sign this driver, or suggest how to sign it officially for free, since its developer can't?

Comment: so the internal speaker doesnt show up as an audio device in `Playback devices`?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: The problem is if the driver is a kernal mode driver (I don't know if it is or not) it must be signed specifically by the [Windows Hardware Dev Center Dashboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_certification/2015/04/01/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10/), you can only do that if you submit the driver to microsoft.