# How can i set my computer to beep once every hour after i booted it without using external software?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, boot

Here's the thing: I am spending like 10 hours a day on my computer because of work, and i've read an article about how bad it is for my body, and the way to counter this as much as possible is to stand up for a minute every once an hour.

So, i need my computer to beep every hour, right after i booted it. I've did some research online, copied a code made by some random user to a txt file, turned it into a .vbs file, and then put a scheduled task for it on my Windows10. The problem is, this thing works every hour regardless of when i booted my computer. (For example it beeps on 1:00-2:00-3:00-:4:00)

What i need is my computer to beep once an hour AFTER i boot it, regardless of minutes. Let's say i booted my computer at 1:52, i need it to beep at 2:52, then 3:52 and so on. Not on a certain time period like i mentioned above. Is this possible to do without me having to download some stuff ? Thanks all for your help in advance !

Comment: I wonder if you don't miss the point of the exercise. It won't harm you if you stand up the first time only half an hour after booting your PC and even if you sat down just 8 minutes ago, you might just overhear it and go on and _wait_ for the next beep.

Comment: yeah, you are right, i know it won't matter much and i'm nitpicking here, but i'm kinda upset that i can't get a simple thing like this done in the year 2018, honestly got kinda obsessed with this small thing just because of this reason now.

Comment: Create simple VBS script beeping each an hour and place it into windows sheduler task fired on user logon.

Comment: I think it **is** actually possible within Task Scheduler. Just set a trigger as follows: _Begin the task: at startup,  Repeat task every: 1 hour_

Comment: If you post the content of the script it might be that someone can modify it to take the current time before setting its alarms.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this only if your PC speaker generates beep sound.

1. Create a batch file `beep.bat` using `echo @echo (Alt-7)>beep.bat` at command prompt. Do not type `(Alt-7)` as is. Instead type `Alt + Numpad 7` at command prompt. [Source](https://www.linux-noob.com/forums/topic/214-make-a-batch-file-that-beeps/).
2. Modify `Beep.bat` as shown in picture. `BEL` generates `beep` sound here. `-n 3601` will generate a wait of 3600 seconds (1 hour) using `ping` command. Batch file will run in an infinite loop and generate beep after every 1 hour.

[image]

3. Copy `beep.bat` in `startup` folder of `start menu`. So, batch file will run as soon as you logon to your computer and generate beep after every 1 hour.

[More Details](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt).