# Make windows sounds use the motherboard/internal beeper instead of the default sound device?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, system-sounds

Is it possible to have windows sounds — either just the notification sound or all sounds, whichever is easier — come from the [PC Speaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker) instead of the windows' default sound device? I'm talking about the sounds defined in this tab:

[image]

The point *is not* to disable the default sound device, it should still be available for other audio content like video, music, etc.

**Update:** To clarify following Christopher's answer, I'm fully aware that the internal speaker/beeper is only capable of simplistic sounds, even just a simple beep is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  Back in the 1980s and 1990s, all PCs had little buzzers on the motherboards, and could receive simple instruction to buzz.  The intended feature was to give sequences at bootup like error codes - short short long meant something specific for that motherboard.  Some programs like games could use very short buzzes to create melodic music.  This was not really audio.

Modern motherboards do not always have the buzzers.  I haven't seen one for years.  In any event, the buzzer is not a fully capable audio device.

Windows : [How to make the PC speaker beep from the Windows 7 command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt)

Comment: The fact that the buzzer is not a fully capable audio device is not relevant, I'm just looking to replace windows sounds with simple beeps which the buzzer is fully capable of.