# Is it possible to cause the physical PC speaker to beep in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I'm wondering whether it's now possible to cause the physical PC speaker to beep in Windows 10. There are existing questions on this but their answers appear to be out-of-date; none of the methods mentioned cause a physical PC speaker to actually beep, but instead an artificial beep sound is generated from the sound card.

Is it now literally impossible to beep the physical PC speaker or is there still some esoteric way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the PC speaker beep from the Windows 7 command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

There are several method for causing a beep. I will describe below
some DIY methods.

**Method 1**

Create a `.bat` file with the command `echo ^G`
(meaning `echo`  followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>).
Run it to make a beep.

**Method 2**

- Run the Command Prompt (CMD)
- Position to a folder
- Enter the following command :

  ```
  copy con beep.txt
  ```

  Type the following :
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>,
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>,
  <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- To do a beep, use the command :

  ```
  Type beep.txt
  ```

**Method 3**

Use PowerShell
[Console.Beep Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=net-7.0) :

```
powershell "[console]::beep(500,300)"
```

Comment: Or `Echo/| CHOICE /N 2> nul & rem BEL`, from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079534/how-to-start-a-system-beep-from-the-built-in-pc-speaker-using-a-batch-file/41107788

Comment: All those methods just cause my Windows 10 to play a sound, it does not cause a beep through the PC speaker.

Comment: So what does cause a beep on your computer?