# System beep runs through desktop speakers, I want the motherboard beeper

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, beep-code

I've decided to have some retro feeling and ordered a motherboard beeper.
The one like this:

[image: PC Speaker]

I've connected the red wire to +5v pin on motherboard and the other one to a pin labeled as "speaker".
It's working fine on bios startup and does one single beep.

Now the question is.
If I try using system beeper in windows, e.g. with:

```ps
powershell.exe [console]::beep(500,600)
```

The sound goes either through desktop speakers or headphones. I want the sound to come out of **PC speaker** / **beeper**, whatever it's called, the one connected to motherboard pins.

###### Specs:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Edition | Windows 10 Pro |
| Version | 21H1 |
| OS build | 19043.928 |
| Experience | Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0 |
| MotherBoard | Asus Maximus IV Extreme-Z |

Comment: Do any of the many answers in [How to make the PC speaker beep from the Windows 7 command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt) help?

Comment: Hi, @AndrewMorton! I've just tried the answers mentioned there and also the ^G special char in cmd, all produce sound from desktop speakers. Though I'll have to try the accepted answer, it will take some time to find 64 bit Win XP `Beep.sys`. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @AndrewMorton well, according to the comments this answer is stale for x64 Win-7 or later. Btw, I remember using Win7 PCs on a project back in 2017 where we had no desktop speakers and the motherboard one worked for holding down Num Lock, it did produce a sound with a vanilla system.

Comment: Did you try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/451501/272824)? (N.B. You might want to check whatever you download with virustotal.com and consider that the PC beeper novelty will wear off faster than you can clean your computer of any malware.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
As stated in the comments, [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt/451501#451501) did the trick, **BEEPX** works. It changes the `beep.sys` driver with a working one. And signed by Microsoft.

Links to the driver:
[x86](https://www.waldbauer.com/tmp/dl.php?download=beepx) | [x64](https://www.waldbauer.com/tmp/dl.php?download=beepxp64)

Just in case the website is down, here are the fallback links on Gdrive:
[x86](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UkFJ3fdchDJQlV9Axxfg4TJNeJNscOmS/view?usp=drive_link) | [x64](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13SQw2xUCp3Vs0bJxp7V7JbsPawgsBAvE/view?usp=drive_link)

By publishing those fallback links I do not violate the license as stated inside:

> ### License
>
> This Application and Sourcecode may be distributed freely.
> The Sourcecode is Licensed in Terms of the GNU GPL v3.
> See: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

### Hashsums:

|  | beepx.zip (x86) | beepx64.zip (x64) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Size: | 71803 bytes (70 KiB) | 26868 bytes (26 KiB) |
| CRC32: | 4766B287 | 6DB259A4 |
| CRC64: | 5158EE3F09D4E4BE | 2B08DC7BCDB37D51 |
| SHA256: | A7F9ED13D1D165482BA9E8A78CD02A48FD8BEC53A4886ECE8B24AD02F60131F8 | C36E4E4B34FB99C90A66C115140C59A75980CEACC01F1542421B226A191D53EE |
| SHA1: | 3681907BA22FCB107839CFB17A72CE3B84C96FAA | BA6548D98A07634FB9D23BDEC2989BF6FB3B0558 |
| BLAKE2sp: | 7567A439B1F789E441D33CD69104F5AC49B621D055332148C8DF924316E66DEB | 45B69757948A15C29EAE618EB335581539BFAC2F83B64E610969237EBF4FE0DF |

## Credits / thanks to:

- Ludwig Ertl, the author of **beepx**
- [@andrew-morton](https://superuser.com/users/272824/andrew-morton) for pointing out a thread with a working [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt/451501#451501)
- [@canopee](https://superuser.com/users/147333/canopee) for posting an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt/451501#451501) and [@rustyx](https://superuser.com/users/85760/rustyx) for [providing x64 link](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt/451501#comment1752316_451501)
- [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) for pointing out [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1790338/is-it-possible-to-cause-the-physical-pc-speaker-to-beep-in-windows-10) that I missed, it does not contain a working solution though, anyway, thank you for the [comment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1537503/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-beep-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5#comment2764336_1537503) and willingness to help