# One (or at most two) click listen to sound file

Tags: windows-explorer, audio

On my Windows 7 system, I have a bunch of very short sound files. From their names, I have a general notion what they contain, but I need to listen to the  most likely files to find out if they meet my purpose.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to listen to a file just by clicking on it in Windows explorer. Probably not practical, so I'd like a *very* simple audio file player that I can associate with the file type. When I double-click on the file, the player plays the file, then closes imediately.

Comment: Would adding them all to a playlist in a media player that lets you click to play not maybe work?  That's probably easier to track down.

Comment: @Shinrai Huh. That's actually a good idea. Please move to "answer" so I can award you accept points.

Comment: As requested.  I commented because I wasn't sure if that would be acceptable for some reason.

Comment: If you turn on single-click execution instead of double-click, you will avoid a lot of clicks in the long run.

Comment: Also, can you test if any methods in [101974](http://superuser.com/questions/101974/play-a-sound-maybe-wav-from-windows-line-command) work on your system?  Does `start /min mplay32 /play /close %WINDIR%\media\tada.wav` work?

Comment: @jwpat7 This comment seems apropos: "Using start file.wav is a bad idea. It might take a second to start a bloated media player, just for a single beep. In addition, file associations might be wrong, the media player might not play the file, or it might play it over and over again, etc."

Comment: Isaac, I saw that comment.  Also, I doubt that mplay32 is on your W7 system.   However, it probably is worth an experiment to find out how well it works on your system if you have it installed.  It is easy to script 1-click or no-click operation of players with command-line interfaces.   (On a different topic, and along the lines of previous answer, while the igorware.com/small-player doesn't have a CLI, if you double click on a name it interrupts what it's playing and immediately starts playing what you clicked on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest to simply add them all to a playlist in the media player of your choice, and play them selectively that way.  (There are enough players that will function like this that I'm hesitant to even name names, but personally I still use Winamp Pro.)

Comment: I already have GOM Player, which has exactly the feature you mention.