# Windows10 Shutdown Sound Playing Properly

Tags: windows-10, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have set up a scheduled task to restore the shutdown sound Windows 10 (Pro) is missing by default. I set up that event 1074 triggers powershell.exe playing the sound with this argument:

-c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer 'F:\Folder\shutdown.wav').PlaySync();

The sound starts to play but gets cut in 1-2 seconds, although there's time to finish it before the computer actually shuts down. I started to look for a way to set a minimal duration the task would run without interruption or the computer shutting it down. I was happy to find this thread: [Play a sound (maybe WAV?) from Windows line command](https://superuser.com/questions/101974/play-a-sound-maybe-wav-from-windows-line-command), and thought I could utilize a modified argument:

-c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer 'F:\Folder\shutdown.wav').Play(); Start-Sleep -s 10; Exit;

This would play the first 10 second of the sound which is actually 8 seconds long, but still interrupts the same way after 1-2 seconds.

Are there any other arguments I could utilize to achieve that the sound gets played before the computer shuts down?

Thank you

Comment: I mean, seriously? you've been trying to make win10 play sound during shutdown all through this lockdown time?

Comment: @Sanu_012 Is there a more appropriate time to do this? : ) I guess researching this is not appropriate at all, but now I definitely want to figure this out but cannot do it on my own unfortunaetly.

Comment: windows will shut off all the apps/utils/things that are running when you trigger the shutdown sequence. i _suspect_ that PoSh is being shut off before it finishes. i don't know how to force windows to wait for that operation to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Windows10 has a built in but (at least for me) quite hidden option to force an already initiated shutdown to let finish specified powershell scripts.

So I ended up removing the scheduled task, but kept the original command with the arguments, and saved the line into a powershell script file, like C:\PlayShutdownSound.ps1:
powershell.exe -c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer 'C:\Folder\shutdown.wav').PlaySync();

Then went into the Group Policies section (gpedit.msc)

- computer configuration
- windows settings
- scripts (startup/shutdown)
- shut down
- properties
- powershell scripts
- add powershell script (browsed here for C:\PlayShutdownSound.ps1)
- run windows powershell script first