# How can I play a sound when my Git for Windows Bash command prompt is ready?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bash, powershell, windows-terminal

I use the shell Git for Windows Bash on Windows 10 and I want to play a sound whenever my command prompt is ready. This acoustic feedback should help me to get (back) to my command line when my Terminal window is fully initialized or a command finished executing.

This is my current .bash_profile line:

```bsh
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a && powershell -c "(New-Object Media.SoundPlayer C:/Windows/Media/chimes.wav).PlaySync();"'
```

- The history command is not relevant and comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10901227/15443125).
- The powershell command comes from [here](https://superuser.com/a/528541/1288709). It does basically work, but it's sync and delays my command prompt loading.

How can I make this async? I tried `nohup` and `&` but those did not work here. [Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.play?view=net-5.0) mention method `Play`, but this doesn't create a sound at all.

Comment: How did you try the `&` exactly?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I replaced the `&&` with `&`. It is still sync, but also prints a line of text.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski When I add an `&` at the end instead, it's async just as I want, but it still prints a line. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/qSMYqdK.png

Comment: Note: to add information to the question, [edit] the question. Comments are not for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run something asynchronously (in the background) you place `&` at the end (where `;` could otherwise be). `powershell -c … &` basically should work.

In an interactive Bash job control is enabled by default and `powershell -c … &` triggers a message from the shell when done (even if run from `PROMPT_COMMAND`). Run the command in an explicit subshell to circumvent. It will be like this:

```
(powershell -c … &)
```

The subshell itself will run synchronously, so the current shell won't treat it as a job. The command inside will run asynchronously, but it won't become a job of the current shell.

This should work:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a && (powershell -c "(New-Object Media.SoundPlayer C:/Windows/Media/chimes.wav).PlaySync();" &)'
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much!